# Property does not exist on type 'any[ ]' in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I use Textscript in Next Js. My project goes fine but I've got some warnings in my script like this 'Property does not exist on type any[ ]', with the red line under the name, image, and price properties. I know there is a bunch of similar question but I still don't get it

```js
import axios from "axios";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function Detail() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const productID = router.query.productID;
  const [detail, setDetail] = useState<any[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getDetail = async () => {
      const { data: res } = await axios
      .get("http://localhost:3004/products/" + productID );
      setDetail(res);
    };
    getDetail();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="pt-5 px-28">
      <label className="text-2xl lg:text-3xl xl:text-3xl font-black">Product Detail - {productID}</label>
      <div className="flex w-full gap-5 mt-3">
        <img src={"../" + detail.image} className="w-1/2 rounded-2xl aspect-[4/3]" />
        <div>
          <div className="grid">
          <label className="text-xl lg:text-2xl xl:text-2xl ">{detail.name}</label>
          <label className="text-md">IDR {detail.price}</label>
          </div>
          <p className="text-justify italic py-5">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto sed
            animi unde tempora in. Tempora quos vitae magni modi! Aliquam illum
            sint unde doloribus repellendus nemo facilis eligendi omnis culpa.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: `detail` is an Array - it does not have `name` and `price` properties. What is the format of data returned by `"http://localhost:3004/products/" + productID`?

Comment: thanks for reply, the "name" and "image" would be a string and the "price" would be a number format

Answer (score 1):

```
const [detail, setDetail] = useState<any[]>([]);
```

This code sets the type of variable `detail` to `any[]` which is an array of `any`.

An array doesn't have properties like `price` or `name`, so that's what causes the error. Instead of that, you could set the type of detail to `{ price: string, name: string, image: string }` and initialize this variable with empty strings.

```
const [detail, setDetail] =
  useState <
  {
    price: string,
    name: string,
    image: string,
  } >
  {
    price: "",
    name: "",
    image: "",
  };
```

It seems that you are a little bit confused about the type of detail. Is a a one element or an array of elements?